Correct way to tag objects with YOLOv5
I need to tag a series of images for sewing detection on fabric. I work with the YOLOv5 algorithm.
The problem I have is that it is not clear to me what should be the optimal way to label these sewings.
The image below shows a sewing in the fabric.

As you can see in the image, the sewings are always going to occupy the whole width of the fabric. Initially I had thought of labelling several sections/portions of the sewing (the number of sewings detected is not really important, what really matters to me is that it detects that there is at least one sewing). The image below shows this idea:

However it is not clear to me if this would be a correct method (optimal, rather) or it should be to create a single label that completely encloses the sewing.
On the other hand, according to the labelling tips given in the documentation, the label should exactly enclose the object to be detected, leaving as little space as possible between the object and the bounding box of the label.

Label accuracy. Labels must closely enclose each object. No space
should exist between an object and it's bounding box. No objects
should be missing a label.

Tips for Best Training Results
In this particular case, and given that the sewings will always appear in a very similar way (they will always have a horizontal orientation), these labels would be very thin (with very little height), so it is not clear to me that the algorithm will be able to detect them. In my humble opinion, I believe that slightly increasing the height of the labels would allow the algorithm to detect the sewings more efficiently, since the fabrics that are joined through these sewings may be of the same colour. (the second of the images shows the idea I am talking about).
I would be grateful if you could help me and tell me the best way to do this labelling.
Thank you very much in advance.

you want semantic segmentation.

@ChristophRackwitz. Thanks for the reply. The problem is that YOLOv5 does not fully support semantic segmentation and it is imperative to do this work with YOLOv5. I have no possibility to switch to a different algorithm.

If in your environment the seams may be different depending on the area of the chair it is recommended to classify the different seams (different bounding boxes for the same line).
To give an answer to the issue of instance segmentation.
You can use yolov5 without too many problems, you can learn to use here.
I don't know if you need particular applications, with yolov5 it is often necessary to work on the code to customize the problem
